# Add page number in ACM 2017 SIGCONF Template

Tags: page-numbering, acm

I have to number the pages in ACM2017 proceedings and I am using the `acmart` template. However `\pagenumbering`... commands and `preprint` option for document class do not work. Any suggestions?

Edit: I am using `sigconf`document class, which is available on the following website:
https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template

and as a minimal example in the following link:
http://wisec2017.ccs.neu.edu/acmart.zip

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. There are several potential `acmart` "templates". Please be specific: *Which* document class do you use? Maybe suggest a website?

Comment: For the `sigchi` template `\pagenumbering{arabic}` switched on the page numbers for me.

Answer (score 30):

Please put `\settopmatter{printfolios=true}` before `\maketitle`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\pagestyle{plain}` before `\begin{document}`. If the first page number is not shown, use `\settopmatter{printfolios=true}` also.

Comment: Without \settopmatter{printfolios=true} I had no page numbers on any page even with \pagenumbering{arabic} and \pagestyle{plain} added only the printfolios parameter made page numbers appear.