# I have \page style{plain}, yet no page numbering is showing. How can I solve this?

Tags: page-numbering

My paper initially did have page-numbers, I do not know what has changed in the mean time that now I do not perceive any page-numbers any more. I tried playing with or even removing \pagestyle{}. Yet nothing happens. **What am I missing?**

This is my setup:

```
\documentclass[nonacm,sigconf]{acmart}

% PACKAGES IMPORT
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{numbers,notesep={: }}

\def\bibpreamble{All the sources have been accessed between the months ... 2020, this also counts for the footnotes.}

\usepackage[font=small,skip=3pt]{caption}

\settopmatter{printacmref=false}
\renewcommand\footnotetextcopyrightpermission[1]{} % removes footnote with conference information in first column
\pagestyle{plain} % removes running headers

\begin{document}

\input{titlepage}

\begin{abstract}
....
\end{abstract}

\keywords{alpha indicators,...}

\maketitle
\input{content}

\newpage
\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{references}

% \onecolumn
\appendix
\onecolumn
\section{Appendices}
In this section, the supportive attachments are included to the study....

\subsection{Appendix A - Interview Questions}
...
\subsection{Appendix B - Interview Transcripts}
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: you have posted a _lot_  of code but almost none of it is related to the page style, and we can not run your example as it `\input` s files that we do not have. Please make a small complete document that shows the problem and delete every `\usepackage` line not needed in the example.

Comment: Possibly duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/358088/31034

Answer (score 2):

Kept in the input files an all.

Just added:

```
\settopmatter{printfolios=true}
```

before:

```
\maketitle
\input{content}
```

And page-numbering reappeared again.